# How to increase the height of the combobox control in mfc?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to increase the height of the combobox control.Increasing the width is happening.But when I am trying to increase the combobox height it is not getting increased.I am very clear I want to increase control vertical height.Usually the combobox control I created is as follows.

[image]

As shown in the above image control which is bordered in red color is the combobox control I want to increase the height.If you can have a look at the below image of EDIT control (notice the size of the edit control).Similar to the size of the edit control I have to increase the height of the combobox control.

```
CString str;
CSize   sz;
CDC*    pDC = m_comboCtrl.GetDC();

m_comboCtrl.GetLBText(0, str);
sz = pDC->GetTextExtent(str);

m_comboCtrl.SetItemHeight(-1,50);
```

After increasing the vertical height the text in the control is very small ,how can we make the text to get fit to the control(which is similar to the normal text in default combobox control).But text in the control is as follows,

[image]

Can anyone please let me know how can make the text to be centred to the control which should look like in the below image.The text in the above image at the top ,But I want to make the text to be centred as of text in standard control.
[image]

Comment: [ComboBox_SetItemHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb856487.aspx) or the respective MFC implementation [CComboBox::SetItemHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs2b25yt.aspx). `index`/`nIndex` must be -1 to set the height of the selection field.

Comment: @IInspectable ,After passing the sz.cy=50,the combobox height got increased.Can't we make the text in the combo to fit exactly to the control.After height modification the combobox control is as shown in the original post.Please refer that image and kindly let me know can we make the text to be fit to the control eventhough I increase the height.

Comment: @IInspectable, I has updated my post kindly have a look at that and please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: This is a different topic and I would recommend starting a new question for that. Since you have found an answer to your initial question consider leaving an answer (see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).

Comment: @IInspectable,Regarding vertical alignment of text in the combo,as you suggested to ask it as a separate question I did it Please refer this link for that question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171457/how-to-make-the-text-to-be-centred-in-combobox-after-increasing-the-combobox-hei)  and I request you to have a look at that question and please let me know your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increase the height of the combobox we need to do like this in OnInitDialog() as follows,

```
CString str;
CSize   sz;
CDC*    pDC = m_comboCtrl.GetDC();

m_comboCtrl.GetLBText(0, str);
sz = pDC->GetTextExtent(str);

m_comboCtrl.SetItemHeight(-1,50);//CCombobox m_comboCtrl;
```

Here 50 in SetItemHeight Indicates the y-Coordinates which in our term is referred as height now .After adding the above code snippet in the OnInitDialog(), the combobox looks like (refer original post where I added the image of the combobox control after increasing the height(Image 2)).

Answer (score 3):

Following the instructions on http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.com/2008/03/vc-mfc-how-to-set-combobox-dropdown.html:

In the MFC designer

1. Click on the arrow in the dropdown control: a resize rect will appear.
2. Resize the height of the dropdown.

Voilà.

Answer (score -2):

Set the Type property to Simple in the Properties window